# integrating two small php codes together

Tags: php

I am using php simple dom parser. I have a list of urls (i.e. urls.txt) which I need to download in plain text. What I am trying to achieve here is that iterating urls, extracting html/text and writing extracted texts into a text file (i.e. plain.txt) incrementally. I have written two separate codes, but I need more insight about successfully integrating them into a single one in order to automate the process. Thank you.

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$Handler = fopen("urls.txt", "a+");
$Urls = fgets($Handler);

while (!feof($Handler)) {
    $Urls = fgets($Handler);
    echo $Urls ."<br />\n";
    }
fclose($Handler);

?>

<?php

$html = file_get_html('http://example.com')->plaintext;
$Dump = fopen("plain.txt", "a+");
fwrite($Dump, $html);
fclose($Dump);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a function for the second script:

```
function func($url) {
    $html = file_get_html($url)->plaintext;
    $Dump = fopen("plain.txt", "a+");
    fwrite($Dump, $html);
    fclose($Dump);
}
```

and then your first script become:

```
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$Handler = fopen("urls.txt", "a+");
$Urls = fgets($Handler);

while (!feof($Handler)) {
    $Urls = fgets($Handler);
    func($Urls);
}
fclose($Handler);
```

Comment: Could you please be more specific? What is the error? Also what returns the fgets?